# How to write information in a database either in SQL or C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I have a database in SQL that looks like this:

```
UID FILE_DATE_PROCESSED FILE_NAME DATE_ENTERED
```

In this database, every time I add a file, column 2 should contain the last time I entered the file, and column 4 should contain the time I am entering the file now.

My problem is, I do not know how to get those columns to do that. For example: when I try to put in a starting date, it keeps giving me an error that the cell is null, and after trying everything I could think of I can't get rid of that error message. So my first question is, for the result that I want, do I do this in SQL or do I do this in my c# console application, and my second question is what is the syntax that I need in order to get this accomplished. Below I have an example of what I am looking for as a result:

```
UID   FILE_DATE_PROCESSED  FILE_NAME DATE_ENTERED
random year/month/day time  filename  current time
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing information from SQL Server to C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742494/writing-information-from-sql-server-to-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a SQL snippet that should insert into those columns:

```
INSERT mytable (UID, FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, FILE_NAME, DATE_ENTERED)
SELECT newid(), '2015-12-31 19:32:45', 'myfilename.txt', getdate()
```

Comment: This is the error message I got from executing the snippet:"Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier"

Comment: Since you didn't post your table definition, I had to guess the column definitions.  I've edited the answer to use `NEWID` instead.

Comment: How do I find the table definition?

Comment: I think that the newid got rid of my data because I can't access it anymore